# Is it possible to render a partial by passing a local variable for the collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 5.2.2 I am trying to render a partial using a local variable as the collection, but when running a test to `get` the view I get an error in the partial:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x00000007503de8>:0x000000093f2240>
        app/views/work_centers/_item_kanban.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_work_centers__item_kanban_html_erb__413475955005549970_77587680'
        app/views/work_centers/kanban.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_work_centers_kanban_html_erb__2029427675221229249_77567000'
        app/views/work_centers/kanban.html.erb:4:in `each'
        app/views/work_centers/kanban.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_work_centers_kanban_html_erb__2029427675221229249_77567000'
        test/controllers/work_centers_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:WorkCentersControllerTest>'
```

**work_centers_controller.rb**

```
def kanban
  # Get hash of form {"Laser"=>["Item1", "Item2"], "Brake"=>["Item2"]}
  @wc_items = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
  WorkCenter.all.each do |wc| 
    @wc_items[wc.name] = Item.where('id IN (SELECT item_id 
                                            FROM routings 
                                            WHERE work_center_id = ?)', wc.id) 
                             .where('id NOT IN (SELECT item_id 
                                                FROM status_updates 
                                                WHERE work_center_id = ?)', wc.id) 
                             .pluck(:number)
  end
end
```

**kanban.html.erb**

```
<% @wc_items.each do |wc, items| %>
  <%= render partial: 'item_kanban', collection: items %>
<% end %>
```

**_item_kanban.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to item, class: "list-group-item" do %>
  <%= item.number %>
<% end %>
```

In other views I render a partial using a collection instance variable (e.g. `@items`) and reference the singular variable in the partial (e.g. `item`). I expected this partial to behave the same way using a local collection variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it

```
<%= render partial: 'item_kanban', collection: items, as: :item %>
```

Now you can access

```
<%= link_to item, class: "list-group-item" do %>
  <%= item.number %>
<% end %>
```

When you did

`<%= render partial: 'item_kanban', collection: items %>` will give you a `item_kanban` local variable and not a `item` variable.

So you need to specify it by `as: :item` now you can access `item`